# Space traveler infected by spider bite is destroyed by Earths' defenses upon his return

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

I read this story in an old comic book about a space traveler who lands on a planet of spiders. They invade his spaceship and one of them bites him. He returns to Earth but realizes he is infected. He also knows the spiders can travel on radio waves so he remains on radio silence. He finally drops a capsule with his story and the Earth defenses blow him out of the sky.  Probably read it in the 1960s. What was the comic?

Comment: You should make a separate question for the second story. It makes it easier to find, thus you increase your chance of having answers, and it also makes it easier to find both the question and the answer afterwards. Also, if you could give us more information, such as when you read those comics for example, it would help in finding it.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the question is closed for having more than one question in it. If you take it down to one (and optionally put the other one in its own question), you will likely have it re-opened.

Comment: Sorry. First time on the site.

Comment: No worries. All of us were new once. Except Valorum. They sprung up full-formed from the aether.

Comment: _" knows the spiders can travel on radio waves"_     -   What?!